# Suggestion required - Use 3rd party UI grid or build own grid from scratch?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, kendo-ui, nuget, telerik-mvc

The project will be built in MVC4 using Entity Framework.

First of all, The targeted grid should be looking like this(It's just a sketch I've made graphically, But it should like this in the end):

[image: Grid UI and functionality illustration]

What will it contain, what I am questioning and what I have done so far:

*These are all the steps i've done until now created without any grid/ 3rd party grid/ helpers to avoid restrictions when receiving the project's actual HTML.

1. Data retrieved by dynamic grouping - (Done)
2. The data is sortable(ViewBag sorting) and have paging(IPagedList) (Done)
3. Filtering each row with distinct value like in the picture example, Running ranges/searches within - Not sure how to implant it without using UI grid - Not done yet.
4. Exporting grid , Adding rows dynamically from within the grid in a list and updating it on demand - Also something that a UI grid could suggest in much easier manner , Not done yet.

So from what you've understood so far, Should I work and could I work with a 3rd party grid that could handle all those options without restriction or should I build all those options manually like i've build the sorting/paging so far?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to note down your requirements and if you cant achieve it the crucial part in Grid, then going for the 3rd party controls would be better choice.

For MVC Grid, please check the demo links of leading products such as Telerik, Syncfusion.

[Syncfusion MVC Grid demo](http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/ui/grid)

[Telerik MVC Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid)

You can evaluate these controls for some period and if it satisfies your needs, you can go ahead with one product.

Mostly all product vendors would give an Export option for Grid to PDF/Excel/Word.

**UPDATE:**

I guess Syncfusion MVC Grid will satisfy your requirement. They have filtering with essential features.

- It will load distinct values in the filter choice list.
- You can filter string values with casesensitive and vice versa.
- Can be able to filter values according to its datatype.
- Can be able to filter values using customer filter.
- Can be able to filter using filter tokens.

Better check the below links.

http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/ui/grid/Filtering/ServerFiltering

http://help.syncfusion.com/ug/asp.net%20mvc/grid/default.htm#!documents/howtofilterdatausingfiltertokensinthefilterbar.htm

Comment: Too global as i've already reviwed one of those product aleady. Ill give the filtering more focus now, Which product can provide the custom filtering like i've illustrated in my question? If possible give similar sample or refer me to it, Thanks.

Comment: you can find more about some sort of custom filtering in KnedoUI at the following link : http://demos.kendoui.com/beta/web/grid/filter-menu-customization.html